# Texts in a scaled html container slightly jumps on everytime when the bootstrap tooltip shows

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am having a div element(container) which gets scaled based on window width and height. Inside the container, I am having some Tool icons which shows the Tooltip on mouseover. I have used bootstrap tooltip.

The issue here is, when I mouseover the Tool icon the texts in the container slightly blured and jumps for a time and return backs to normal state. This happens every time when the tooltip shows.

But, on normal state (i.e) when the content is not scaled there is no problem at all.

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.  
  </p>
  <div id="toolicons">
    <div id="toolone" class="tool" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
      Tool Icon
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css goes here

```
#container {
  width:500px;
  transform:scale(1.25);
  transform-origin:left top;
}
#toolicons
{
  margin:8px 0px;
}
.tool{
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

and javascript is here

```
$('#toolone').tooltip();
```

Comment: Need to see code......

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)